# i18n on Ruby on Rails, < and > gets replaced by &gt ; &lt ; when not intended

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, yaml, escaping

I am creating locale files for internationalization in a rails app, and have a url that I want translated with tags included ,  for example

html.erb

> <%= t(foo.bar.xxxx) %>

yml file

> foo:    bar:
>         xxxx: "xxxx"

result

> &lt ;a href=
>   "/info/index.html"&gt ;xxxx</a&gt ;

which breaks my links. I do not have an h on the ruby part, so shouldn't this work?
Or should I just not have html tags within the yml file?

Rails version is 3.0.1
Ruby version is 1.8.7 p249

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Your HTML YAML keys need to have a `_html` suffix:

```
foo:
  bar:
    xxxx_html: "<strong>Some HTML Here</strong>"
```

Doing this Rails will mark the string has `html_safe` and will render out the HTML instead of converting it to `&gt;` and `&lt;`.

You need to reference it with the full key name as well, Rails doesn't automatically see the _html suffix when you call `xxxx`.

```
<%= t 'foo.bar.xxxx_html' %>
```

Comment: this worked beautifully, the prefix is pretty handy for identification too, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Rails is preventing injection attacks by preventing model data from being displayed as actual markup.  The raw function prevents that conversion.

Does

```
<%= raw t(foo.bar.xxxx) %>
```

work?

Comment: This worked just as well as the other one, was not aware of the raw method. This could come in handy some time, thanks for the info.